# Failing updates after upgrade to mongodb and mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have recently upgraded mongoid from 2.0.2 to 2.2.0 and mongodb from 1.8.1 to 1.8.3. After the upgrade I am facing weird issues while updating the user doument, which embeds a lot of other documents. For details, please see [mongoid google group discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/dcc3579fbc27e0d)

There are two cases I have identified which fail consistently,

- First involves, using `accept_nested_attributes_for` for a embeds_many and deleting one embedded document and adding other. In this situation mongoid tries to pull and push to the user document in a single update call, which mongodb whines about in logs(verbose=true).
- Second involves, deeply embedded documents. Mongoid tries to push embedded document and set the deeply embedded document in a single update call, which mongodb whines about again.

I have created the [gist](https://gist.github.com/1194447) for easy recreation and logging info.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Update:**

It has been accepted as a [confirmed bug](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1219) in mongoid 2.2.0 and set to be solved in 2.2.1. For now reverting back to 2.0.2 solved my problem.

This issue has been fixed in latest mongoid.